# Wordpress Admin Can't Login - ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser

Tags: wordpress, cookies, authentication, admin, blocked

I have an issue with a multisite setup where I can no longer login to any of the sites. They all run from separate domains.

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

I have tried the solutions on previous questions to define the COOKIE_DOMAIN in the wp-config, however I receive an error saying that this already defined? I believe it may be coming from wp-super-cache plugin, however I am not 100% sure.

I have tried to rename all of my plugins the hope to deactivate them however I am still unable to login.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it's already defined then there is already a line about COOKIE_DOMAIN in your wp-config. Change that existing line from false to true. The define-function creates a named constant, and once this has been created they can't be changes (that why it's a constant).

And super-cache doesn't cache php files.